# Access SharePoint 2013 outside server farm with AD Users

Tags: alternate-access-mapping, server-farm, extranet, web-application-zones, external-users

I want to know how to access my SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise when I'm not at work. The SharePoint Server is located at work. And I want to be able to access the Web Application E.G from home with my AD users only.

The Web Application uses Windows Authentication only.

What I have tried without any luck: Configure an alternate access mappings with Internet Zone. Both VIA GUI and Powershell. Created a host entry in DNS.

I hope someone can help me.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's mainly two options:

- **Use a VPN**, and access you SP sites as you would do from the inside of the network.
- "**Publish your SP server on the Internet**":
  Usually, you use a dedicated server known as a "publishing server" or a "reverse proxy" (like Microsoft TMG). That server has a public IP address (and you register a public DNS name to point to it). When a request comes in, the reverse proxy is configured to show up an authentication form. User inputs his/her credentials in fields, and then the reverse proxy will forward these credentials to SP (SP will see a request coming in as if it was a "normal" request, Windows-authenticated, from the local network). AAM will also come up in the game, but that's the small part of the whole configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try the VPN method. :) I believe  I can solve this issue now. :)

Answer (score 2):

1. You could create a VPN network from your home to your office network. (Recommanded)
2. Alternate access mappings isn't just working for External access, you need to configure too in your router and your DNS server, that's a little complexe in this situation.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try to use a VPN network.